# Android inter thread communication best practices with ViewModel and CameraX?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-viewmodel, android-camerax

I have the following scenario (view code below):

1. Get an `ImageProxy` from the loop of the `ImageAnalyzer` use case of CameraX
2. Analyze the image (takes about 20 ms) and return some information, `close()` the `ImageProxy`
3. Analyze the extracted information via AsyncTask (takes about 500 to 3000 ms)
4. If successful, show results

I have some fragments which are dependent on how successful Task 1. and 2. are (in particular a PreviewView fragment and some result page). Currently they get notified by the `ViewModel`. When the image gets analyzed by either Task 1. or 2. I set a state with `viewModel.analyzerState.postValue(<newState>)`. This is of course not ideal, since I need to listen to that state in my Tasks as well in case the previous image produced a result that I can show to the user.

My problem is now the following:
When a result is ready, Task 1. or 2. might still be running and produce another result which will then trigger the UI to update twice. I do not want that, but I still want the Tasks to run in parallel in case the previous task failed (which happens quite often). When I'm sure I have a result, I want the Tasks cancelled (I'm already calling `cancel()` on the AsyncTask, but that's not working). I think my problem is using the `ViewModel` as a messaging tool for inter thread communication, since I set the state in Task 1. as well as in Task 2. and listen to it in the loop.

The only information I could find was using Kotlin coroutines which apparently are made for working with the `ViewModel`, but I am using Java.

What is the standard approach for this kind of problem? How do I communicate between the various threads and fragments *safely*?

Code:

```
void analyzeImage(ImageProxy imageProxy) {    // loop called by CameraX
    if (viewModel.analyzerState.getValue() == 'done') {
        imageProxy.close();
        return;
    }

    viewModel.analyzerState.postValue('extracting');

    Data data = extractData(imageProxy);

    imageProxy.close();

    if (data.isValid()) {
        viewModel.analyzerState.postValue('analyzing');
        new DataAnalyzeTask.execute(data);
    } else {
        viewModel.analyzerState.postValue('idle');
    }
}

// UI listens with
viewModel.analyzerState.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), state -> { /*...*/ } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time and a lot of changes, but now I have a solution that is working for my purposes. So instead of using `AsyncTask` and the `ViewModel` for communication, I implemented my own `Task` class which is basically just a `Runnable` with some callbacks. These callbacks allow me to communicate with the UI. The UI then propagates data changes with the `ViewModel` (on the main thread). To ensure I'm on the main thread, I execute the callbacks in the main thread handler:

```
Handler mainThreadHandler = HandlerCompat.createAsync(Looper.getMainLooper());

// in Task class:
mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        callback.onSomethingHappend(result);
    }
});
```

My custom `Task`s are executed in a thread pool via an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);   // should be called only once when the application launches

executor.execute(new Task(data, callback));
```

I think there might be a simpler solution using `ListenableFuture` (since I more or less reimplemented those with my `Task` and `TaskCallback` class), but I did not want to add Guava to my project for now.

To ensure I can cancel my tasks, I used `AtomicBoolean` and set the value to false once I had some results:

```
atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(/*expectedValue=*/false, /*newValue=*/true);
```

Here are some useful resources:

https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/java-threads
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/listenablefuture